# Azure resource.managerdeployment Script ARM template

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-deployment

I'm having an issue with an inline deployment script in ARM, I'm trying to get an ObjectId from a script and it appears to work in powershell the script when it runs.

It retrieves the ObjectId no problems and then all I want it is to give me the output of the ObjectId in the Azure portal in deployment script/outputs section.

I have followed Microsoft's documentation deployment scripts to a tee so I think it must be something very small I am doing which is causing an issue. I thought someone experienced in here might be able to have a quick look and see the issue immediately. I'm still quite new to coding and also the azure devops space.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {},
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts",
      "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
      "name": "getUserObjectId",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "kind": "AzurePowerShell",
      "identity": {
        "type": "UserAssigned",
        "userAssignedIdentities": {}
      },
      "properties": {
        "azPowerShellVersion": "",
        "arguments": "",
        "scriptContent": "
                $output = (Get-AzADUser -UserPrincipalName 'user@email').Id 
                Write-Output $output 
                $DeploymentScriptOutputs = @{}
                $DeploymentScriptOutputs['text'] = $output
                ",
        "cleanupPreference": "OnSuccess",
        "timeout": "PT1H",
        "retentionInterval": "P1D"
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "objectId": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference('getUserObjectId').outputs.text]"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script you provided is only missing a value for `azPowershellVersion`. Unfortunately you don't mention anything about any errors that you are encountering. I have a feeling that you get an error like this:

> The template output 'objectId' is not validut JToken type : Template output JToken type is not valid. Expected 'String'. Actual 'Null'.Please see https://aka.ms/arm-syntax-outputs for usage details.

I believe you are not actually getting the UserId from AAD. Instead your script is failing silently. You should look at the script execution logs:

> az deployment-scripts show-log -g myresourcegroup --name getUserObjectId

I made the managed identity a global administrator for testing and got the desired results. You probably want to give it more restricted permissions. A working script example will look like this:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {},
  "variables": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts",
      "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
      "name": "getUserObjectId",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "kind": "AzurePowerShell",
      "identity": {
        "type": "UserAssigned",
        "userAssignedIdentities": {
          "<managedidentityresourceId>": {}
        }
      },
      "properties": {
        "azPowerShellVersion": "8.3",
        "arguments": "",
        "scriptContent": "
                $output = (Get-AzADUser -UserPrincipalName 'user@email').Id 
                #$output = (New-Guid).ToString()
                Write-Output $output 
                $DeploymentScriptOutputs = @{}
                $DeploymentScriptOutputs['text'] = $output
                ",
        "cleanupPreference": "OnSuccess",
        "timeout": "PT1H",
        "retentionInterval": "P1D"
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "objectId": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference('getUserObjectId').outputs.text]"
    }
  }
}
```

You can also add `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` to the beginning of your deployment script to make sure the whole deployment is failing if the script encounters an error.

Comment: That was exactly the error I was getting; I'm going ahead and trying your implementation. with your managed identity I've created a managed identity with owner contribution I can't see global administrator on my end unfortunately. but thankyou again for such a detailed response, I really appreciate it

Comment: @JoshuaMartin glad I could help. You need to go into the Active Directory Roles to assign Global Administrators. If your question was answered, please consider marking the answer as accepted by using the green check mark. I'd also appreciate an upvote.